# Changed part of path and need to redirect old to new

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have updated country code in the base path and I am attempting the redirect users that end up going to:
www.example.com/**uk**/etc1/etc2/etc..

www.example.com/**gb**/etc1/etc2/etc..

But also sometimes also www.example.com/**uk**#etc

I thought this would be fairly trivial in mod_rewrite I cant get anything to work.

The closest I feel I have come is the following rule, but nothing happens when I land on uk.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L] #this is active already on the page

    RewriteRule   ^/uk(.*) /gb(.*) [R]
</IfModule>
```

Edit:

This seems closer but I am getting stuck in an endless loop:

`RewriteRule   ^uk(.*) /gb$1 [R]`

Edit 2 / **(3) Answer**:

This seems to redirect correctly(is correct):

```
RewriteRule ^uk(.*)$ /gb$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

But the formatting is broken on the page, looks like some loop problem.

But the formatting is incorrect, If I swap the two RewriteRules the formatting is correct but the uk => gb conversion doesn't seem to get called at all.

#### Answer

Be careful of Rewriteconditions, I failed to notice the significance of them and I removed them for the original index.php rewrite which meant it could not locate any media.
I failed to take notice of the rewrite conditions which applied for the original index.php

Comment: Why you rewriting everything to index.php? This is actually what causing the loop. You need to remove this line `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`.

Comment: @Sameh It is one of Magentos base behaviours, so it is required unfortunately. But it was the cause of the problem, there was a bunch of RewriteConditions that I had to apply for both rewrites in order to get it to work. In hindsight I did not give enough information and I am sorry for that. The correct solution for the redirect was in my edit 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on        
RewriteRule   ^/uk(.*) /gb$1 [R=301,L]
```